# Moving data of DataGridview from left to right by clicking on the ColumnHeader

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview

I have encountered a strange problem.

When the program loads, everything is normal and the created rows are displayed correctly.
But when I click on the DataGridView header for ascending and descending sort, the DataGridView data in all rows starts moving from left to right.

I do not know where the reason is.
I made this change in this function but the problem is not solved.

```
private void dgvWF_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    dgvWF.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
    dgvWF.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
}
```

This problem did not exist before.

[image]
[image]
[image]

EDIT 1:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;            
string myXMLfile = @"C:\Users\PC\Desktop\XMLFile1.xml";

            ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(myXMLfile);
            dt = ds.Tables["XMLFile1"];
            if (dt != null)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
                dataGridView1.Refresh();
                dataGridView1.RowCount = dt.Rows.Count + 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
                }
                dataGridView1.Columns[0].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
                dataGridView1.Rows[dt.Rows.Count].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            }
            else if (dt == null)
            {
                dataGridView1.RowCount = 1;
                dataGridView1.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            }
```

EDIT 2:

My problem was solved.

```
RichTextBox rtbRootName = new RichTextBox();
string myXMLfile = @"C:\Users\PC\Desktop\XMLFile1.xml";
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds.ReadXml(myXMLfile);
                DataTable dt = ds.Tables["XMLFile1"];
                if (dt != null)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
                    dataGridView1.Refresh();
                    dataGridView1.RowCount = dt.Rows.Count + 1;
                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        rtbRootName.Clear(); rtbRootName.Text = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = rtbRootName.Rtf;
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
                    }
                    dataGridView1.Rows[dt.Rows.Count].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGray;

                }
                else if (dt == null)
                {
                    dataGridView1.RowCount = 1;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
                }
```

Comment: How do you populate the grid? Set `dgvWF.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft`. and try.

Comment: Please see EDIT1. I used `DataGridViewRichTextBoxColumn.cs` also. I have not had this problem before but I do not know what change in my program has caused this problem. The data moves until it is completely out.

Comment: How can we get location of data in cell if datagridview?

Comment: I can't see DataGridViewRichTextBoxColumn nor DataGridViewRichTextBoxCell. For now, try the default DataGridViewTextBoxColumn to see whether the bug is in the custom column. Also, move `dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();` to before the `if` block. Remove `dataGridView1.Refresh();` and `dataGridView1.RowCount = dt.Rows.Count + 1;` and use the `.Rows.Add(..)` method instead. `dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dt.Rows[i][0].ToString().Trim(), dt.Rows[i][1].ToString().Trim());`.

Comment: I did not understand how to use DataGridViewTextBoxColumn. And My problem was not solved. But I made these changes and the problem was solved. Please see EDIT2.
RootName is not the text but it is RichTextBox. DataTable is text and the problem was here.

Comment: If `rtbRootName` is a RichTextBox and the value of `dt.Rows[i][1]` is RTF codes, then you should set the [rtbRootName.Rtf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.rtf?view=net-5.0). i.e. `rtbRootName.Rtf = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();`. And don't forget to call `rtbRootName.Dispose();` when you don't need it any more.

Comment: Thank you. I use rtbRootName in the following cases:
`On loading` 
`In adding` 
`In editing` 
`In search` 
But I only create it once, when the software opens.
If I do Dispose, do I have to create it for each use?

Comment: No, keep it alive as long as you need it. Dispose of it when you close the Form.